# Number of elements of order $r$ in the symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

The question I am asking is already asked [here.](http://Finding%20the%20number%20of%20elements%20of%20order%20two%20in%20the%20symmetric%20group%20%20S4S4)

I want specially the general part, i.e. number of elements of order $r$ in the symmetric group $S_n$, $n\ge 4$.
Is there a general rule?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint : any permutation $\sigma$ can be written as a product of cycles with disjoint support, and those cylces therefore commute. The order of a cycle is...

Comment: L.c.m of the order of the product cycles.

Comment: This question also appeared at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627130/).

Comment: Oh ! I missed it then

Answer (score 1):

Every subset $S\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $\operatorname{lcm} S=n$ and map $S\to\Bbb N$ with $\sum_s sf(s)=n$ contributes $\frac{n!}{\prod_s s!^{f(s)}f(s)!}$ to the total count ...

Comment: Thanks.,its the same formula for finidng the number of elements in a conjugacy class of a cycle ,right ?

Comment: Well! Will you please cross check the problem : How many elements of order 6 are there in $S_7$ ? , After calculating I found the number to be 1260,as first I found the number of elements in the conjugacy class of a cycle of length 6,then I worked out the number of elements in the conjugacy class of composition of 2cycles(one of length 3 and other of length 2,as the order of the cycle of their composition is lcm of 2 and 3 and hence 6).Now these 2 conjugacy classes are different as their elemnts do not have the same cycle length,so the required number of elements of order 6 is 1260. Right ?