# Number of elements of order $m$ in the symmetric group $S_m$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

What is the number of elements of order $m$ in the symmetric group $S_m$ given that $m$ is a prime.

I believe it is $\left(m-1\right)!$.

Because on cycle form the its possible Length is $m$ only. Only $1$ cycle is possible with length $m$ and I guess it had $\left(m-1\right)!$ possibilities only.

Comment: $S_m$ is defined for all positive integers $m$, whether prime or composite.  This problem is harder when $m$ is composite.  For example, $(12)(345)(6)$ has order $6$ in $S_6$.

Comment: More generally, [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627130/how-many-elements-of-order-k-are-in-s-n)

Comment: Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

For prime $m$ your result is correct.  We cannot comment on your reasoning as you did not present it.  To get a cycle of length $m$ you can send $1$ to anywhere but $1$, which is $m-1$ choices.  Then you send than number anywhere but $1$ or itself, which is $m-2$ choices.  This results in $(m-1)!$ elements in $S_m$ with period $m$.

Comment: Given that the OP has not asked the question they wanted to ask I think this would be better as a comment.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  I don't see where OP wants a different question.  i added some detail.